# How to pass a string to a command (Linux)

Tags: linux, command

I have a case where I am passing a content of a file to a command like this:

```
cat file_name.txt | my_command
```

But I want to pass a string directly, without reading a txt file content. So I want to have something like this:

```
"my file content as a string" | my_command
```

But of course I am getting an error "Command not found."

Please help me to come up with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do

```
echo "my file content as a string" | my_command
```

Comment: yeees, sure :)!!!

Comment: No, no, no my question was very simple but I have casually missed that “echo” will work fine!, please roll back to your prev answer.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. echo "foo" will actually pass "foo\n". It has to be echo -n "foo".

Comment: That depends on what your my_command is expecting

Answer (score 4):

Echo is fine, with bash you can also use a [here string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) if you want.  For example:

```
grep tak <<<"foo bar tak"
```

Or:

```
foo="bar tak"
grep tak <<<$foo
```

Answer (score 1):

echo "my file content as a string" | my_command

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type :

```
my_command "my file content as a string"
```

Comment: Whether that would work, depends heavily on the command used

Comment: in my case that is not a solution, sorry